# How to maintain status of index while loading multiple images in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var imageArray = [];

  for(var i =0; i<3; i++){
    imageArray[i] = new Image();
    imageArray[i].onload = function(i) {
      $("#cell_"+i).append(imageArray[i]);
      imageArray[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    imageArray[i].onerror = function() {
      alert("not loaded");
    }

    imageArray[i].src = '/home//dummy_'+i+'.jpg';

  }
```

I wan to load some images from a list of dummy list of images.
but during onload i lost the context of i, 
it always points to i =3 (last value of loop).
ho to preserve this i so that when it comes to onload, it will give me exact i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in another function:

```
imageArray[i].onload = function(ic) { // ic is a copy of i in the scope of this function
    return function() { 
      $("#cell_"+ic).append(imageArray[ic]); // ic is borrowed from the outer scope
      imageArray[ic].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}(i); // call the function with i as parameter
```

Alternatively, you can use bind to ... bind a parameter to your function:

```
imageArray[i].onload = function(i,event) { 
// added the event parameter to show that the arguments normally passed to the function are not overwritten, merely pushed to make room for the bound ones
      $("#cell_"+i).append(imageArray[i]);
      imageArray[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}.bind(null, i); // the function will always be called with he value of i passed to the first argument
```

NOTE: Behind the scenes, this is the same solution.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind